# Different input voltages for IR LED and TSOP

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, 555, infrared, proximity-sensor

I'm designing a circuit where I need to detect an obstacle in the front efficiently in ambient light at a distance not more than 3-4 cm.

For that I'm planning to use IR sensor system,
IR LED as transmitter ([See here for IR LED](https://www.evelta.com/content/datasheets/012-IR928-6C(6-1).pdf)) and TSOP as receiver (TSOP1738 [datasheet](https://www.batronix.com/pdf/tsop17xx.pdf%5D)) or (TSOP38238 [datasheet](https://robu.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/tsop382-DATASHEET2.pdf)).

The design is to operate the IR transmitter at ~38 kHz with use of a 555 timer IC ([See here for 555 timer](https://www.evelta.com/content/datasheets/ne555-datasheet-TI.pdf)) at 5 V and sense the reflection from obstacles with a TSOP1738 or TSOP38238, which will have Vcc at 3.3 V as the controller can only handle 3.3 V at input GPIO pins.

The circuit will be like this (for reference) but I need to operate at different voltages:

[image]

Question is,

1. Should I operate the IR LED at 5V as the 555 needs a minimum of 4.5 V to operate and operate the TSOP1738 or TSOP38238 at 3.3 V as the controller can only handle 3.3 V at the input terminal?
2. Should I operate the IR LED and TSOP both at 5 V and do some kind of buck conversion or voltage divider at the input terminal of the controller for the TSOP's 5 V output to be converted to 3.3 V?

Comment: It depends from a lot of things. Sure you need 5V for the NE555 if it needs at least 4.5V. If your MCU can support 5V voltage then you don't need to do anything. But please note that your device may not work, because TSOP38238 will filter out continuous carrier according to datasheet. If you have an MCU, why bother with the NE555 at all?

Comment: @Justme Yes, I can directly operate IR LED at 38KHz from microcontroller, but the reason for using NE555 is that I don't have many GPIO's to use, most of them are used for other parts of the control circuit. That's why, NE555 can do its job without occupying any of my GPIO and also from code perspective I don't need to continuously keep operating the IR LED!

Comment: @Justme can you please tell a little bit more about that why device won't work with TSOP38238?

Comment: I already said the part datasheet says it suppresses continuous signal. You can read the datasheet and find out the same thing. It is not meant to detect a continuous 38 kHz signal. It is meant to detect bursts of 38 kHz signal, with certain requirements how long the bursts are and how long the gaps are between bursts.

Comment: @Justme thanks, I missed to read that part! So if I want to use TSOP38238 then I need to operated IR LED from MCU, right! Or I think I can use TSOP1738 [https://www.batronix.com/pdf/tsop17xx.pdf] for this same circuit?

Comment: You should verify it can be used with continuous burst. But as proximity detection modules exist, why not buy something that will be suitable for what you want, instead of building one from components not meant for proximity detection?

Comment: Actually I'm designing an integrated PCB with other control systems too along with proximity detection, similar module are available but for integration on same PCB I'm designing this (similar module, https://robu.in/product/infrared-obstacle-avoidance-sensor-module/), but main doubt I had was if I operate IR LED on 5v and TSOP on 3.3v, will it work?

Comment: If you read the datasheet, it says TSOP will work at 3.3V. But still you can't use it for proximity detection because datasheet says it filters away continuous carrier.

Comment: As for 1, it's neither. Your series resistor will adopt the LED Vf to whatever Vcc you have as long as it's Vcc>Vf within reason.